# How to get/set text into View Text ? MonoMac - Xamarin, IB - Xcode,

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin

I'm creating an app in Xamarin with MonoMac. My UI is created with IB from Xcode.
I created View Text area, but I can't set/get text to/from it.
I tried to search, but without success.

I need something like TextField.StringValue used for TextFields.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create outlet for your text field. Xamarin will auto generate the property after that and you will be able to set TextField.StringValue. See the doc here:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html

Comment: sorry, I probably explained wrong. TextField.StringValue is working. I  need ViewText.StringValue and it's not working

Comment: Is ViewText custom control?

Comment: I have this in my designer.cs : 
MonoMac.AppKit.NSScrollView showArea { get; set; }
I need showArea.StringValue

Comment: NSScrollView don't have StringValue property. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/

Comment: so how would you suggest to resolve this? 
I need something like textField, but for many lines and I need to get string from it and set data to it ?

Comment: Replace the NSScrollView with UITextView, it is multiline and scrollable. "Text" property gets and sets the displayed text.

Comment: IB doesn't know UITextView, only NSTextView. :/